# Tab browser's title not updating on live website (but updates fine on local host)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to change the browser's title of my live React site with the `index.html` file in my `public` folder and successfully changed from `OLD TITLE` to `NEW BROWSER TITLE FOR SITE` when deployed on localhost. But my live site's browser title is still stuck on `OLD TITLE`.

I might be missing something very minor, but any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

I've added most of my `index.html` file below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css"
    />

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link
      href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.12.0/mapbox-gl.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <title>NEW BROWSER TITLE FOR SITE</title>
  </head>
.
.
.
.
</html>
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache for the site. Another option is to ensure that server does not cache the `index.html` file

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, just cleared my browsing data (Chrome) and the live site still has the old browser title. I'll elaborate below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with my Firebase permissions, and was solved after running `firebase login --reauth` in terminal, followed by `firebase deploy`.